# Spotify API - Error Fetching Access Token using Refresh Token

Tags: authorization, spotify, refresh-token

I am trying to display the top tracks of what I listen to on my personal website and I have having trouble getting past authentication. Specifically, the error gives me an invalid request saying that the "refresh_token must be supplied" even though I am passing it in the parameters.

```
import { Buffer } from 'buffer';
import querystring from 'querystring'
const CLIENT_ID = import.meta.env.VITE_APP_CLIENT_ID;
const CLIENT_SECRET = import.meta.env.VITE_APP_CLIENT_SECRET;
const REFRESH_TOKEN = import.meta.env.VITE_APP_REFRESH_TOKEN;

const basic = Buffer.from(`${CLIENT_ID}:${CLIENT_SECRET}`).toString('base64');
const TOKEN_ENDPOINT = `https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token`
    
    const getAccessToken = async () => {
        const response = await fetch(TOKEN_ENDPOINT, {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
            Authorization: `Basic ${basic}`,
            'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
            },
            body: querystring.stringify({
                grant_type: 'refresh_token',
                REFRESH_TOKEN,
            }),
        })

        return response
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The correct body would be:

```
     body: querystring.stringify({
                grant_type: 'refresh_token',
                refresh_token: REFRESH_TOKEN,
            }),
```

This is because:

```
{ REFRESH_TOKEN }
```

gets expanded to:

```
{ REFRESH_TOKEN: "abcdef" }
```

The spotify API requires the token to be passed in by the name of `refresh_token`.

Read more here:
https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/web-api/tutorials/code-flow